# Pyspark calculated field based off time difference

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
trip_distance | tpep_pickup_datetime | tpep_dropoff_datetime|
+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
1.5           | 2019-01-01 00:46:40  |  2019-01-01 00:53:20 |
```

In the end, I need to get create a speed column for each row, so something like this:

```
trip_distance | tpep_pickup_datetime | tpep_dropoff_datetime| speed |
+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------+
1.5           | 2019-01-01 00:46:40  |  2019-01-01 00:53:20 | 13.5  |
```

So this is what I'm trying to do to get there. I figure I should add an interium column to help out, called `trip_time` which is a calculation of `tpep_dropoff_datetime` - `tpep_pickup_datetime`. Here is the code I'm doing to get that:

```
df4 = df.withColumn('trip_time', df.tpep_dropoff_datetime - df.tpep_pickup_datetime)
```

which is producing a nice trip_time column:

```
trip_distance | tpep_pickup_datetime | tpep_dropoff_datetime|              trip_time|
+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
1.5           | 2019-01-01 00:46:40  |  2019-01-01 00:53:20 |   6 minutes 40 seconds|
```

But now I want to do the speed column, and this how I'm trying to do that:

```
df4 = df4.withColumn('speed', (F.col('trip_distance') / F.col('trip_time')))
```

But that is giving me this error:
`AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`trip_distance`/`trip_time`)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`trip_distance`/`trip_time`)' (float and interval).;;`

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to convert your time to `unix_timestamp` which is in unit of seconds, and then you can do the subtraction, which gives you interval as integer that can be further used to calculate speed:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('speed', f.col('trip_distance') * 3600 / (
  f.unix_timestamp('tpep_dropoff_datetime') - f.unix_timestamp('tpep_pickup_datetime'))
).show()

+-------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----+
|trip_distance|tpep_pickup_datetime|tpep_dropoff_datetime|speed|
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----+
|          1.5| 2019-01-01 00:46:40|  2019-01-01 00:53:20| 13.5|
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----+
```